# How to handle query with parameter in python graphene

Tags: python, graphql

```
class ProductQuery(graphene.ObjectType):
    products = graphene.List(Product)

    def resolve_products(self, info):
        return get_all_products()
```

Above are my code for query all product with no param. What is I want to query product by manufacture_id? How to do I do the resolver?

There is no document on [their official site](http://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/types/schema/).

Answer (score 7):

```
class ProductQuery(graphene.ObjectType):
  products = graphene.List(Product, id=graphene.Int())

  def resolve_products(self, info, id):
    return Product.objects.filter_by(manufacture_id__exact=id)
```

You have to add the parameter you want to query by.

Comment: Please add a short explanation to your code. Code only answers are rarely helpful for others and tend to get deleted.